# Symfony 4 - update JSON user roles

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have entity User with field roles:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];

public function getRoles(): array
{
    return $roles = $this->roles;
}

public function setRoles($roles): self
{
    $this->roles[] = $roles;

    return $this;
}
```

I want to add functionality to update user role from ROLE_ADMIN to ROLE_USER. I tried this in my controller but instead of replacing ROLE_ADMIN with ROLE_USER it inerts this: "ROLE_ADMIN""ROLE_USER". This is my controller:

```
public function updateuser(Request $request, $id) {
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $usr = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
    $usr->setRoles("ROLE_USER");
    $entityManager->persist($usr);
    $entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all its best practice that every users has at least a default role like `ROLE_USER`. If you want to give users extra roles then you add them with beside `ROLE_USER`, like for example `ROLE_ADMIN`.
2. Now take a close look how arrays work in PHP. Let's take the code of you setter function `setRoles`.

When you write the value assignment like this `$this->roles[] = $roles`, then a **value is added to the array** . Thats why you in you code you have both roles inside you array now. The already existing `ROLE_ADMIN` and after the function call you added `ROLE_USER`.

When you write the value assignment like this `$this->roles = $roles`, then the **whole array is overwritten with the new value**.

**Conclusion:**

Thats how you code should look like if you want a simple solution:

```
   public function setRoles(array $roles): self
   {
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
   }
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setRoles` function only accepts array.

So your code should change accordingly:

```
$usr->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);
```

Furthermore, if you want to store it as json, you can use `json_encode`:

```
$usr->setRoles(json_encode(["ROLE_USER"]));
```

Comment: With the current setter the OP would end up with `[['ROLE_USER']]` because of `$this->roles[] = $roles`. Additionally. doctrine converts the [type="json"](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#json) to a string on the database end and to an array or null type on the PHP end, so you would not want to pass a json_encoded string either.